# In a Google Document, how do you embed one list in another?

Tags: google-drive, list

I'm having problems embedding a list inside another a google document like so:

- item in main list

  - item in embedded list
- another item in main list
- yet another item in main list

The document already has some embedded lists like this so I assume it must be achievable, although they may have been added in OpenOffice or LibreOffice before being imported to Google Docs, but I don't seem to be able to create any new ones.

If I press the list button to try and do so, it makes the current line no longer a list item.  The number list button just changes the entire of the current list to a numeric list.  The indent one place button, which I would expect to be the correct thing to press, breaks the list in weird ways.

Searching for an answer I just find lots of information on listing the documents you have in your Google Docs account, so any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Create the first item of the list
2. Click on the **Bulleted list** or **Numbered list** icon from the menu
   [image]
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. The second item of the list will be automatically created
5. Click on the **Increase indent** button
   [image]
6. You are done.

[image]

In your case, it might be the fact that the document was created in a different editor and the CSS rules behind are broken by the indentation button. In this case, your options are either to edit the CSS/HTML source or to recreate the list entirely, copy/pasting the text in plain, without the whole formatting rules.

Comment: Thanks.  I suspect its because the document was created in a different editor then.  A shame Google Docs doesn't properly import odt files into its own style format completely, but I suspect since this particular group edited file will only be in GoogleDocs from now on, the best solution will be to recreate the lists from scratch as you say.

Comment: If you copy/paste it, make sure you do it in plain text, otherwise it will just keep the formatting. Paste it into Notepad or TextEdit first (of course, assuming that is set to plain text format) and then into your document.

Comment: If I highlighted and copied just the text it worked fine.  Of course it meant I had to do each line of the list separately but I guess those are the breaks!